# Nested Case Statements in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, case

So, I'm trying to run a SQL Statement to select and entire DB for upload in an ETL process, but I want to create a calculated column for the number of days between a ticket opening and being closed.

The IF-THEN logic is like this:
IF the department is Grounds Maintenance, and there's a foreign key match with a second table, and there's specific task type, then use formula A
ELSE
IF INCIDENT_RESOLVED_DATE IS NULL, then use formula B
ELSE use formula C

I think my CASE logic is solid, but it keeps bringing me back the same row over and over again. This tells me I'm missing something. I'm almost positive it's something to do with the WHEN statement on the first part of the CASE statement, but if I knew, I wouldn't be asking.

```
SELECT 
    a.*
    , a.REPORTED_DATE
    , a.CLOSE_DATE
    , a.INCIDENT_RESOLVED_DATE
    , CASE 
        WHEN DEPARTMENT = 'Grounds Maintenance' 
        AND a.INCIDENT_ID = b.SOURCE_OBJECT_ID
        AND b.TASK_TYPE_ID = '11501'
        THEN (to_date(b.ACTUAL_END_DATE, 'DD-MM-YYYY') - to_date(a.REPORTED_DATE, 'DD-MM-YYYY'))
        ELSE CASE 
            WHEN a.INCIDENT_RESOLVED_DATE IS NULL THEN (to_date(a.CLOSE_DATE, 'DD-MM-YYYY') - to_date(a.REPORTED_DATE, 'DD-MM-YYYY')) 
            ELSE (to_date(a.INCIDENT_RESOLVED_DATE, 'DD-MM-YYYY') - to_date(a.REPORTED_DATE, 'DD-MM-YYYY'))END 
    END 
AS 
    DAYS_TO_RESOLVE
FROM 
    CMEM_CS_SERVICE_REQUESTS a, jtf_tasks_b b
WHERE 
    EXTRACT(YEAR FROM a.REPORTED_DATE) > 2009;
```

Thoughts?

Comment: First of all, you have cross join in your query. Is it intended or a mistake (likely)?

Comment: I believe that's the problem. Where am I creating the Cartesian?

Comment: You are selecting from two tables separated by commas and no join condition in the where clause. This is why you should always use explicit `JOIN` keyword based join.

Comment: Blargh. I was hoping it was more complicated than that.

Comment: If you need further help, add some sample data and expected result with explanation of the logic..

Comment: How would I write the join so that it doesn't limit the rows to the ones where there is a join between a and b? Like, I don't want it in my overall WHERE clause, so that I only get the rows where a.INCIDENT_ID = b.SOURCE_OBJECT_ID.

Comment: Please include some sample data to clarify.

Comment: Sounds like you want an **outer join**.

Comment: On a separate issue, `WHERE 
    EXTRACT(YEAR FROM a.REPORTED_DATE) > 2009;` is a guaranteed performance problem.  Try `a.REPORTED_DATE >= to_date('01/01/2009','MM/DD/YYYY')  and a.REPORTED_DATE < to_date('01/01/2010','MM/DD/YYYY')`